# asp net core database initialization (seeding the data)

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, initialization

I want to initialize the DB with the data, whenever such data doesn't already exist. In this example, whenever the table "Country" is empty, data will be inserted. The following is the code from the "Startup" class:

```
public class Startup
{
    // lines of code...

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        // lines of code...

        app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>().Seed();
    }
}

public static class DbContextExtensions
{
    public static void Seed(this ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        AddCountries(db); // <= WARNING HERE
    }

    private static async Task AddCountries(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        if (await db.Country.CountAsync() == 0)
        {
            db.AddRange(
                new Country { Name = "England", Code = "En" },
                new Country { Name = "France", Code = "Fr" }
                );
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The designated line results with a compilation warning "Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed". OK, it's a synchronous method and I'm calling an async method. What is the best way of resolving this issue (both options are fine: to launch async processing od data insertion while continuing the execution, or to wait for its completion and then continuing).

Also, I wonder if it's be better to use ApplicationDbContext.OnModelCreating instead of Startup.Configure for the described DB initialization.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you dont need the result then you can simply return void instead of Task.That would save you the warning

```
    private static async void AddCountries(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {   
        if (db.Country.Any())
        {
            return;   // DB has been seeded
        }

        db.AddRange(
            new Country { Name = "England", Code = "En" },
            new Country { Name = "France", Code = "Fr" }
            );

       db.SaveChanges();
   }
```

However you should use await to perform the actual operation(Task) not to count the rows.

Comment: OK, this eliminates the warning. I'm leaving the question open for the second part of the question (ApplicationDbContext.OnModelCreating vs Startup.Configure).